# Unable to start Activity, No view found for id

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new with Android development, so this is probably a rookie mistake but, I am stuck.

I want to start an activity when clicking on the menu, but the following exception  shows up:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mygymroutine.mygymroutine/com.mygymroutine.mygymroutine.activities.ActivitySchedule}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d008b
>   (com.mygymroutine.mygymroutine:id/fragment_schedule) for fragment
>   ScheduleFragment{39f1839 #0 id=0x7f0d008b ...

This is the code related:

```
public class basic extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_schedule);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.basic, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }
    private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {
        Intent intent=null;
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_schedule:
                intent=new Intent(this, ActivitySchedule.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
```

Activity code

```
package com.mygymroutine.mygymroutine.activities;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import com.mygymroutine.mygymroutine.Fragments.ScheduleFragment;
import com.mygymroutine.mygymroutine.R;


public class ActivitySchedule extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acivity_schedule);
        if(savedInstanceState==null){
            ScheduleFragment fg = new ScheduleFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_schedule, fg)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
package com.mygymroutine.mygymroutine.Fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.mygymroutine.mygymroutine.R;

public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);
        FloatingActionButton fab=(FloatingActionButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_schedule);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle("Schedule");
    }
}
```

Fragment Schedule xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_schedule"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Schedule"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_schedule"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:tint="@android:color/background_light"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity schedule xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mygymroutine.mygymroutine.activities.ActivitySchedule">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your Fragment should `return rootView`, by the way

Comment: change `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);` to `return rootView;`

Comment: In the XML, where is `R.id.fragment_schedule` set? Which file?

Comment: I forgot to upload the interested xml files, now there are

I changed the return but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_schedule, fg)
                .commit();
```

You are passing `R.id.fragment_schedule` as the container of the fragment. Where the fragment will be inserted. However, `R.id.fragment_schedule` is part of your `Fragment`. So, it was not inflated yet. You can't use it as container since it was not created yet.

I think you want is:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mygymroutine.mygymroutine.activities.ActivitySchedule"

   <!-- ADD LINE BELOW -->
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container" > 

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And change this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_schedule, fg)
                .commit();
```

to this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fg)
                .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In. The onOptionsItemSelected method add the following
(This method brings a parameter - MenuItem item)

```
switch (item.getItemId())
    case R.id.myFirst
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MyFirstActivity.class));
    case R.id.mySecond
        startActivity (newIntent(this, MySecondActivity.class));
```

And so on. You may define a layout for the activity with necessary views. You may also declare the activity in the Manifest file.

This works. I am starting my activities from the main like this.